# Java Basic Game

Tags: java

I'm tryin to develop a small text-based fighting game and I'm using eclipse to help me out. I have two classes a Hero and Villian.

Hero Code so far:

```
public class Hero
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int Health;
    private int Punch;
    private int Kick; 
    private int Special;
    /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Hero
    */
    public Hero()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        Health = 100;
        Punch = -30;
        Kick = -25;
        Special = -55;
    }
```

Villian Code so far:

```
public class Villian
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int Health;
    private int Punch;
    private int Kick; 
    private int Special; 

    /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Villian
    */
    public Villian()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        Health = 100;
        Punch = -25;
        Kick = -30;
        Special = -50;
    }
```

I want to make it turn-based as well so that when the hero attacks, it's the villian's turn. But I'm having trouble trying to construct a suitable method for the attacks. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is to use inheritance.

You want to have one class called `Entity` which holds everything all things need on the game field:

```
public abstract class Entity {
    private int Health;
    private int attackDmg;

    public Entity(int health,  int attackDamage) {
        this.health = health;
        this.attackDamage = attackDamage;
    }
}
```

Then the two classes you currently have simply inherent everything from `Entity`:

```
public class Hero extends Entity {

    public Hero() {
        super(100, 30);
    }
}
```

and Villian:

```
public class Villian extends Entity {

    public Villian() {
        super(100, 20);
    }
}
```

Now you probably want to have some methods that makes the Entity take damage. Because everybody should be able to take damage it comes into the Entity class. Also you probably want to have an attack method, that tells you how much damage the entities does:

```
public abstract class Entity {
    // [...]

    public void takeDamage(int damage) {
        health -= dmg;
    }

    public void attack() {
        return attackDamage;
    }
}
```

Now you can write in your controller class (that handles all of the turn based logic):

`player.takeDamage(villian.attack());` (Given that `player`is your `Player`and `villian` your `Villian`).

Of course this only is a small example, you could also make a method that take a `String` as an argument, which represents the method of the attack (like "kick" or "punch") and then return different amounts depending on the attack type.

Further infos to inheritance:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm and http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/java-inheritance-types/

You might also be interested in a game making tutorial:
http://www.gametutorial.net/

Answer (score 0):

You might take a variable like flag and set its value to 1 when hero's turn and its value to 0 when villan's turn

```
if(flag==1)
   {
      villans turn;
      flag=0;
   }
else if(flag==0)
   {
      heros turn;
      flag=1;
   }
```

This works